# Python, Web Scrapping

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I tried scrapping a website using BeautifulSoup and no matter the method or selector I try it always returns an empty list. This was supposed to print the top 1001 songs on the billboard chart

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

date = input("Which year do you want to travel to? Type the date in this format YYYY-MM-DD: ")

response = requests.get("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/" + date)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
song_names_spans = soup.find_all("span", class_="chart-element__information__song")
song_names = [song.getText() for song in song_names_spans]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong `.find_all()` call. Try using a `.select()` to use a CSS selector and call instead and copy-paste the list of classes that song titles have from the developer tools in your browser (I chose the first four: `c-title`, `a-no-trucate`, `a-font-primary-bold-s`, and `u-letter-spacing-0021`, and it worked). Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

date = input("Which year do you want to travel to? Type the date in this format YYYY-MM-DD: ")

response = requests.get("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/" + date)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
song_names_els = soup.select('h3.c-title.a-no-trucate.a-font-primary-bold-s.u-letter-spacing-0021')
song_names = [song.getText().strip() for song in song_names_els]

print(song_names)
```

Note that all song titles are `<h1>` tags, not `<span>`s, so you should search for `<h1>`s instead.